# How to open Eclipse editor programatically without passing an IFile object

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to open an editor programmatically in Eclipse RCP without passing an `IFile` object or any URI of the file. I don't want to use any e4 implementations also.

Can any one of you help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Is this your editor or some existing editor?

Comment: Hi @greg-449: Existing editor!

Comment: You must give an existing editor the input it expects. It will fail if you do not.

Comment: I see you're new to SO

If you feel an answer solved the problem (probably Greg's answer), please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented the editor yourself, you can use `IWorkbenchPage::openEditor()` to open editors. For example.

```java
MyEditorInput input = new MyEditorInput();    
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().openEditor( input, "org.example.meditor" );
```

Answer (score 0):

For existing editors you must open the editor using a `IEditorInput` that the editor expects. Editors will usually fail if the input is not correct.

Not all editors require an `IFile` input (`IFileEditorInput`) some accept `IURIEditorInput`, `IPathEditorInput`, `IStorageEditorInput` or some other input that the editor defines.